# Run Ghost blog locally with python script

Tags: python, ghost-blog

I have installed ghost blog locally on Windows 10.

To run ghost, I run the following the commands manually on Windows prompt;

```
$ C:\Users\johnK\Dropbox\jk\ghost
$ ghost start
```

I want to automate this with a Python script. This is how my Python script looks.

```py
import os
    
os.system(r"C:\Users\johnK\Dropbox\jk\ghost")
os.system("ghost start")
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error;

```
'C:\Users\johnK\Dropbox\jk\ghost' is not recognized as an
internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Working directory is not a recognisable Ghost installation.
Run `ghost start` again within a folder where Ghost was installed
with Ghost-CLI.
```

I am using Python v3.9, Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to replicate the behavior you need first understand what you are doing in your Windows prompt:

```
$ C:\Users\johnK\Dropbox\jk\ghost
```

means you change the working directory to be `C:\Users\johnK\Dropbox\jk\ghost` (it's kinda shortcut for `cd C:\Users\johnK\Dropbox\jk\ghost`) and then:

```
$ ghost start
```

executes `ghost` executable (`.bat`, `.exe` whatever it is) located in that directory and passing `start` as invocation argument. So in fact your `ghost` executable could theoretically be run with one-liner:

```
$ C:\Users\johnK\Dropbox\jk\ghost\ghost start
```

To mimic that in your python script you can either try to just run above oneliner or first change current working directory for Python and then run your executable:

```py
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\johnK\Dropbox\jk\ghost")
os.system("ghost start")
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. Tested to work. Why didn't I think of that?